# How to join data from multiple locations in your Firebase DB?

Tags: firebase

I have an index of notification ids associated with a user X. When I want to display these notifications I need to fetch them from the user X's notifications index which just contains the

a) id of the notification (nid)

b) status: "read/unread"

But I also need to go to

a) /notifcations/nid to get my notification data: text and fromUser

b) /users/fromUser to get the user data for that user

My question is about structure.

Did i structure my data properly and if so, how can I fetch all this information inside the Notification and when ready, present it to angular for displaying on the screen.

Here is my take on that below. Any critique (code/structure/anything) is welcome. Thanks.

P.S.
Also if I am replacing POJOs in firebaseArray with instances of Notification, how would that affect my DB when I say edit the notification and save it back to Firebase. How does AngularFire know what to save back?

```
/* Notifications */

.factory('Notifications', function(firebaseUrl, NotificationsFactory){
  var ref = new Firebase(firebaseUrl);

  return {
    getNotificationsForUser : function(uid){
      var userNotifRef = ref.child('users').child(uid).child('notifications');
      return new NotificationsFactory(userNotifRef);
    }
  }
})

.factory('NotificationsFactory', function($firebaseArray, Notification) {
  return $firebaseArray.extend({
    $$added : function(snapshot, prevChild){ //called anytime a 'child_added' event occurs
      return new Notification(snapshot);
    }
  })
})

.factory('Notification', function(firebaseUrl, $q, Users) {
  var notifRef = (new Firebase(firebaseUrl)).child('notifications');
  var usersRef = (new Firebase(firebaseUrl)).child('users');

  var mainDeferred = $q.defer();
  var notifDeferred = $q.defer();
  var userDeferred = $q.defer();

  var Notification = function(snapshot){
    this.$id = snapshot.key();
    this.status = snapshot.val().status;
    this.message = null;
    this.from = null;
    this.to = null;

    notifRef.child(this.$id).once('value', function(snap){ //change to on if expect notification to keep updating
      var data = snap.val();
      this.message = data.message;
      this.from = data.from; //user id
      this.to = data.to; //user id
      notifDeferred.resolve();
    });

    notifDeferred.promise.then(function(){
      this.from = Users.getUser(this.from);
      this.to = Users.getUser(this.to);
      this.from.$loaded().then(function(){
        this.to.$loaded().then(function(){
          mainDeferred.resolve();
        })
      })
    })
  };

  Notification.prototype.ready = function(){
    return mainDeferred.promise;
  }

  return Notification;
})
```

Comment: Check out [firebase-util](http://firebase.github.io/firebase-util/#/)'s NormalizedCollection, which can make joining easier.

Comment: Any constraint that prevents you from just storing a list of notifications by uid? The general mantra is work hard on writes to make reads easy. This seems the opposite.

Comment: Thanks, firebase-util's NormalizedCollection is a charm!